# Почему тиражируется ошибка в популярном учебнике русского языка?

Tags: пунктуация, тире, приложение

Н. Г. Гольцова, И. В. Шамшин.  Русский язык. 10 – 11 классы. Учебник для общеобразовательных школ.
Популярный учебник, часто переиздается.

**Правило из учебника:**

Второе тире опускается, если по условиям контекста после обособленного  приложения должна стоять **запятая**:  *Васильев – **высокий молодой человек, сидящий в кресле,** за  весь вечер не проронил ни слова.*  Сравните: *Васильев – **высокий молодой человек** – за  весь вечер не проронил ни слова.*

Но это неверно, правильно будет так: *Васильев – **высокий молодой человек, сидящий в кресле,** – за  весь вечер не проронил ни слова.*

Откуда взялся  молодой человек Васильев – неизвестно, вероятно, предложение придуманное (и попутная мораль: не надо придумывать предложения).  Тиражируется  на всех учебных сайтах. **Если это ошибка, то почему за 15 лет  никто ее не заметил.**

Правило Розенталя применяется здесь формально,  без понимания его сути. http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=111#pp111
Примечание. Одно тире (первое или второе) опускается:
1) если по условиям контекста после обособленного приложения ставится запятая.

И вопрос: Как нужно изменить правило Розенталя, чтобы таких ошибок не было?

Comment: Само предложение _замечено_ настолько, что включалось в материалы по подготовке к ЕГЭ для учителей и учащихся (Бр. Сычёв, 2018, гл. Тире при приложении. Примеры).

Comment: @Sharon Спасибо большое за интересный вопрос! Ответить — после Вас — не решилась.

Answer (score 1):

Если ориентироваться на параграф из Розенталя (со всеми его пунктами), предложение не выглядит ошибочным, несмотря на то, что оно отличается по основанию для постановки запятой от примеров, поясняющих "контекстную запятую" (п.1 Примечания к п.10). Ошибка с опусканием второго тире была бы в случае вставки, выпадающей из структуры предложения, чего не происходит с приложением к подлежащему, за которым следует сказуемое. Косвенно подвести "предложение с Васильевым" под примеры Розенталя позволяет пункт 8 того же примечания, поясняющий "возвращение" тире, которое могло бы быть опущено по основному правилу: оно ставится-таки в случае, когда приложение распространено и имеет внутри себя запятые. Соответствующий пояснительный пример (о грузинской архитектуре) отличается от "васильевского" предложения именно этим, в остальном имея подобную структуру (сказуемое находится после приложения). В том развёрнутом примечании встречаются не всегда последовательные отступления с постановкой и опусканием тире, но это могли быть проблемы корректуры; так или иначе, всё проясняется примерами.

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ, но я ничего не поняла.1)  Сколько тире нужно ставить и почему?  (Это ГЛАВНЫЙ вопрос). 2) Откуда взялось это предложение, из художественной литературы? И в каком виде его тиражируют на  ЕГЭ  (с одним или двумя тире). 3) И вопрос по Розенталю: у него идет Примечание для одного тире, а потом появляются пункты с двумя тире (два приложения, грузинская архитектура). Это как?

Comment: Тире одно (в упомянутом сборнике - тоже). Предложение похоже на придумку. Розенталя так отредактировали - да, в "Примечании" не везде ясно, что автором отнесено к текущему пункту, а что к нескольким последующим. Страница с Васильевым: https://books.google.ru/books/content?id=5lcyDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT287&img=1&zoom=3&hl=en&ots=6nqfKRducl&sig=ACfU3U3nBRWaBUsazBVxZ6nvIaKsShSTng&w=1280

Comment: Там должно быть два тире. Вы бы сколько поставили?

Comment: Если бы не заглядывал в Розенталя, интуитивно поставил бы два. Но сейчас заметил разницу между произвольной вставкой с двусторонним тире и приложением между подлежащим и сказуемым. _Васильев - это был молодой человек, сидевший в кресле, - ни разу..._

Comment: Заметили разницу и  ставите одно тире?

Comment: Да. А откуда следует, что "точно два"?

Comment: Во-первых, я уверена в этом и могу объяснить почему. Во-вторых, я подстраховалась (кто будет мои объяснения слушать) и задала вопрос Грамоте.  Про учебник ничего не говорила (для объективности). Они ответили, что нужно два тире. (Кстати, Ваша правка переводит приложение в вводную конструкцию, а там всегда два тире).

Comment: Грамота свой ответ не пояснила :)

Comment: Да, они не всегда поясняют ответы. Может, знают почему, а может быть, интуитивно решили, что нужно два тире. Но это уже их проблемы. Первое слово дороже второго.

Answer (score 1):

Честно говоря, я не планировала отвечать на вопрос. Но после второго ответа мне приходится это делать, чтобы не комментировать его.

**Почему правило Розенталя сложно понять?**

Я  считаю его человеком необыкновенным, который знал много больше, чем смог написать. Почему?  Вероятно, считал, что его не поймут. Вероятно, единомышленников и среди коллег было мало, а как  тогда писать для  общей аудитории?

**Я не сомневаюсь, что Розенталь решал задачи с помощью интонационного анализа, иногда в его правилах говорится об интонации.**  Но этот метод тогда был новым, а потом развитие не получил, сейчас же вовсе изгнан из ПАС. **А вот без интонации объяснить и правильно понять тему одного или двух тире при обособлении приложений практически невозможно.**

В этом я еще раз убеждаюсь, читая второй ответ. Практически всё понято неверно. Кроме того, меня смущает редакция правил, в которой явно допущены ошибки (в примечании говорится о случаях постановки одного тире, а примеры приводятся и с двумя тире тоже).

Комментарий к правилам Розенталя http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=111#pp111

Примечание. Одно тире (первое или второе) опускается:

1) **если по условиям контекста после обособленного приложения ставится запятая**: ***Если бы он привлёк к решению вопроса свой прибор — весы, //то понял бы источник ошибки;***

Это встроенная интонация, приложение интонационно вписывается в деепричастный оборот, составляет его часть, паузы нет (короткая произносительная пауза возможна, но собственного ударения приложение уже не имеет).

Запятая, о которой говорит Розенталь, относится **к структуре предложения** (в данном случае к деепричастному обороту).

2) **если приложение выражает конкретное значение, а предшествующее определяемое слово имеет общее или образное значение:**  Прилетели сюда первые ласточки — наши спортсмены // для участия в парусных гонках;

Это также встроенная интонация, приложение интонационно вписывается в простое предложение, паузы нет. Приложение и определяемое слово произносятся в одну фразу.

3) **если приложение стоит перед определяемым словом**: Один из аутсайдеров чемпионата страны — спортсмены клуба «Фили» одержали третью победу подряд (Газ.);  Глашатай лесов — кукушка известила всех о событии;

Это разделительное тире, первая часть предложения имеет **обстоятельственное** значение.
Смысл такой: Несмотря на то, что клуб был в аутсайдерах, он одержал победу (значение уступки).  Будучи глашатаем леса, кукушка известил всех (значение причины).

4) **для внесения ясности, если приложение относится к одному из однородных членов предложения:** В оранжерее разводились магнолии, камелии — цветы Японии, орхидеи и цикламены.

Интонация встроенная, «камелии — цветы Японии» произносится в одну фразу.

5) **при отделении стоящих перед определяемым словом однородных приложений от определяемого слова:** Величайший наш поэт, основоположник русского литературного языка, крупнейший представитель национальной литературы — Пушкин по праву занимает одно из первых мест в истории культурного развития России (при чтении после однородных приложений делается пауза).

Здесь однородный ряд также имеет обстоятельственное значение (будучи…).

**И про Васильева**

***Васильев – высокий молодой человек, сидящий в кресле, – за весь вечер не проронил ни слова.  Васильев – высокий молодой человек – за весь вечер не проронил ни слова.***

Ничего не меняется, приложение **никуда не встраивается и имеет собственную вставочную интонацию,** что и обозначается двумя тире. Запятая закрывает причастный оборот, отнесенный к самому приложению, и к структуре предложения отношения не имеет. **Не о такой запятой говорил Розенталь.**

И зачем надо было придумывать предложение, когда в художественной литературе много подобных примеров.

*Радио – **единственная связь, соединяющая с миром**, – работало исправно (И. С. Соколов-Микитов «Пути кораблей»).  Молодая рыжая собака – **помесь таксы с дворняжкой, очень похожая мордой на лисицу,** – бегала взад и вперёд по тротуару ( А.П. Чехов). Зато сама Мадонна – **прекрасная женщина, спокойно и величественно стремящаяся в лоно Бога-отца,** – поразила Инсарова и Елену (И. С. Тургенев).*

Comment: А вы можете принять свой ответ? Очень интересно.

Comment: Понятия не имею, никогда не пробовала.

Comment: Так попробуйте))) Повторный клик отменит принятие. Галочку можно отменить в любое время, в отличие от лайка (серого треугольника).

Comment: Спасибо! Велели 30 минут подождать, чтобы  ответ был принят.  Что теперь делать?

Comment: А я понятия не имею))) Посмотрим через 30 минут. Если говорят подождать, то, наверно, кто-то будет решать, засчитывать принятие или нет. Но вы всегда можете эту галочку отменить.

Comment: Некогда мне смотреть.

Comment: Наткнулся на такое интересное предложение: *Старший инспектор Пауль Рабе и бывшая возлюбленная Тальхайма — Кристина Ферманн, не очень рады появлению профессора.* Сомнительно использование и тире, и запятой. По Розенталю, вроде бы запятой не должно быть. Или нужно второе тире.

Comment: Нужно два тире.

Comment: Да, но думаю, что можно просто без запятой. Тогда имя не так отделяется от всего предложения.

Comment: Одно тире нельзя, такое тире ставится  для обособления приложения в конце предложения (перед точкой)  или перед структурной запятой.

Comment: По аналогии с кукушкой и подобными примерами. Только согласование в числе не стыкуется. Это нежелательно.

Comment: Какая кукушка? Там совсем другой пример, а здесь обычное уточнение (двумя запятыми или двумя тире). Но запятые по семантике плохо подходят.

Comment: Другой пример, но чуть похоже. У нас тут действующие лица: Пауль Рабе и Кристина Ферманн. Плохо одно выделять в "изолированное" с двух сторон уточнение. У Розенталя кукушка тоже действующее лицо.

Answer (score 1):

"Как нужно изменить правило Розенталя, чтобы таких ошибок не было?" - для этого надо дописать, что запятая, стоящая после приложения не относится к самому приложению, а нужна согласно структуре предложения:

Васильев – высокий молодой человек, сидящий в кресле, – за весь вечер не проронил ни слова.

запятая после "кресле" относится к приложению, поэтому после нее нужно тире.

Увидев Васильева – высокого молодого человека, сидящего в кресле, Иванов закурил.

запятая отделяет деепричастный оборот, после него ставится запятая, а второе тире.

Comment: Нет. У вас придаточное заканчивается после "закурит". А после "человек" должно быть тире.

Comment: Ответ верный, но и комментарий тоже верный. Пожалуйста, исправьте пример, чтобы всё было правильным и можно было поставить одно тире.

Comment: @Sharon Ответ правильный. Розенталь это и имел в виду под "по условиям контекста", но выразился очень образно. Но я бы тире не ставил (именно в этом примере). Дам ещё один ответ, в котором объясню всю суть примечаний Розенталя. И случай с этого ответа тоже. Думаю, что мы с вами поймём друг друга.

Answer (score 1):

А теперь выскажу своё мнение касательно примечаний Розенталя. Вернее, объясню их суть.

"Высокий молодой человек, сидящий в кресле" — это дополнительная информация. Поэтому нужны 2 тире. Здесь смысл в том, что именно Васильев не проронил ни слова, а не человек, сидящий в кресле.

*Глашатай лесов — кукушка известила всех о событии.*
Здесь смысл в том, что именно кукушка известила, а не глашатай лесов. И согласование здесь соответствующее. Разрывать подлежащее "кукушка" и сказуемое "известила" нет смысла.
Сравнить:
*Кукушка — глашатай лесов — известила всех о событии.*

*Один из аутсайдеров чемпионата страны — спортсмены клуба «Фили» одержали третью победу подряд.* || Здесь то же самое.
Сравнить:
*Спортсмены клуба «Фили» — один из аутсайдеров чемпионата страны — одержали третью победу подряд.*

*Величайший наш поэт, основоположник русского литературного языка, крупнейший представитель национальной литературы — Пушкин по праву занимает одно из первых мест в истории культурного развития России.*
Здесь часть перед тире является пояснительной (дополнительной). Её можно опустить, и предложение останется корректным. Но никак нельзя опустить слово "Пушкин", которое является центральным элементом смысла. Поэтому дальше предложение продолжается без тире.
Сравнить:
*Пушкин — величайший наш поэт, основоположник русского литературного языка, крупнейший представитель национальной литературы — по праву занимает одно из первых мест в истории культурного развития России.*

Из двух понятий что-то должно быть основным (центральным элементом смысла), а что-то дополнительным (пояснительным). Именно определяемое понятие (а не определение) является ключевым (основным).

Примечание: слово "определение" использую не как член предложения, а в прямом смысле (*дать определение какому-либо понятию*).

Такое видим и в других примерах Розенталя — дополнительная информация выносится на начало. А разделять центральный элемент смысла с последующей частью предложения вообще бессмысленно.

Здесь суть не в обстоятельственном значении. Хотя это, конечно, способствует корректности предложения.

Поэтому в следующем предложении с придаточным тоже нужны 2 тире:
*Если закурит Васильев – высокий молодой человек, сидящий в кресле, — то за весь вечер не проронит ни слова.*
Центральный смысл такой:
*Если закурит Васильев, то за весь вечер не проронит ни слова.*
Вставка является дополнительной (её можно опустить), что сопоставимо с вводным предложением. Если бы последняя часть относилась напрямую к вставке, то второе тире было бы ненужно.

Comment: «Как сердцу высказать себя, другому как понять тебя?»  Вот никак мы друг друга не понимаем. Вы про ВСТАВОЧНУЮ интонацию слышали?  Это официальный термин, определяется в учебнике: две паузы, общее понижение тона. Похоже на другой уровень речи. В этом случае ставятся два тире. Если ставится одно тире, то ничего этого нет,  нет вставочной интонации. А что есть? Приложение потеряло самостоятельность и стало рядовым элементом другой структуры. Небольшая ПАУЗА сохраняется, но она не подчеркивается, становится произносительной.

Comment: А УДАРЕНИЕ? Ударение может падать, но ЭТО ОБЩЕЕ УДАРЕНИЕ всего оборота/предложения, например:  Если придет Васильев – мой дрУг,  я останусь. Чтобы вписаться в чужую структуру, надо быть компактным, нераспространенным.  Такую интонацию я называю ВСТРОЕННОЙ (но это неофициальный термин).  В противном случае  ничего не получится, вернее, получится ВСТАВНАЯ конструкция, два тире.  Если придет Васильев – высокий молодой человек, мой друг, –  я останусь. (Обособление распространенного приложения оформлено по образцу вставки).

Comment: Ну и про кукушку  еще расскажу.  Все варианты хороши, выбирай на вкус. Но смысловые оттенки и интонация разные. 
 (1) Кукушка — глашатай лесов — известила всех о событии.  (2) Вестница лесов — кукушка   — известила всех о событии. (3) Глашатай лесов — кукушка известила всех о событии.  
1. Вставочная интонация, обособлена художественная метафора. 2. Вставочная интонация, обособлено пояснение. 3. Интонация СПП, обстоятельственное значение: Будучи глашатаем лесов, кукушка известила всех о событии.

Comment: Соглашусь. Но то, о чём я говорю в ответах, — общие закономерности в примерах Розенталя. Он точно так же искал закономерности в литературе — собственных примеров у него мало. И это самый универсальный метод.

Comment: А я оказался прав про кукушку (в данном ответе). Розенталь тоже так считает: Второе тире в этом случае не ставится, поскольку на первом месте стоит не определяемое существительное, а приложение; ср.: *Одно из крупнейших издательств страны — Гослитиздат значительно увеличил выпуск произведений классиков мировой литературы* (сказуемое согласовано со словом *Гослитиздат*). *С утра к воздушным воротам столицы — Внуковскому аэродрому направлялось множество машин* (по смыслу машины направлялись не к «воздушным воротам столицы», а к аэродрому).

Answer (score 0):

Согласен, что необходимы два тире. В учебнике просто кошмар: с "сидящий в кресле" тире нельзя ставить, а без — нужно. Если уже так рассуждать, то при отсутствии обособленного причастного оборота тире тоже не должно стоять. Получается, что всё решает наличие обособленного оборота.

У Розенталя получилось не правило, а нечто общее для галочки, позволяющее опускать тире, оставляя запятую. Но примеры очень хорошие, как всегда.

Сюда подходит правило из третьего пункта: **если приложение стоит перед определяемым словом** — им выступают: *весы, акваланг, имена кинорежиссёров*. А запятые, соответственно трём примерам, закрывают придаточное, деепричастный оборот и причастный.

Не зная правильной пунктуации этих примеров, оформил бы именно так же, потому что постановка тире в них соотносится с правилом, когда сказуемое выражено существительным и можно подставить слово "это". В примерах Розенталя видим:
*свой прибор — весы;

устройство для дыхания человека под водой — акваланг;

юноши, впоследствии ставшие известными кинорежиссёрами, — Григорий Александров, Иван Пырьев*.
Такая вставка не несёт дополнительную мысль или точку зрения, чтобы выделять вторым тире.

Да и вообще, во всех пунктах, кроме последнего, имеем дело с определением и определяемым понятием.

В учебнике определение и определяемое слово поменяны местами.
У Розенталя есть такой пример: *Глашатай лесов — кукушка известила всех о событии.*
Соответственно, меняя определение и определяемое слово местами, имеем:
*Высокий молодой человек, сидящий в кресле, — Васильев за весь вечер не проронил ни слова.*
В таком варианте отсутствие второго тире гораздо естественней.

Comment: Не могу с Вам согласиться практически ни в чём.  Ну вот к примеру: Высокий молодой человек, сидящий в кресле, — Васильев за весь вечер не проронил ни слова.  Нет, такой Васильев не подойдет, так как приложение в такой позиции (по Розенталю) имеет обстоятельственное значение: Будучи высоким молодым человеком, сидящим в кресле, Васильев за весь вечер не проронил ни слова. Ну куда это годится?

Comment: И что именно вам не нравится? Так можно сказать и про кукушку - *будучи глашатаем лесов*. В последнем абзаце просто поставил в таком порядке, как в предложении с кукушкой. Это как дополнение к ответу. Сама суть ответа до этого.

Comment: Всё не нравится, кроме Вас (Вы у меня почему-то  вызывает чувство симпатии). Пожалуйста, прочитайте мой ответ, больше мне нечего добавить. Я рассказала всё, что знаю.

Comment: Прочитал. Ох, лучше бы и не писал последний абзац. Просто поставил в таком же порядке, и всё. Судя по вашему ответу, вы только с ним не согласны.

Answer (score 0):

Хотела обойтись комментарием, но — не получается.

1. Хорошее правило у Розенталя, понятное. И примеры хорошие, понятные.
   А если в каком-то учебнике приведено "понапридуманное" предложение, которое под это правило **никак** не подпадает, то это не вина Розенталя. Нужно просто изъять это предложение — как ошибочное.

   ***Васильев*** [высокий молодой человек, сидящий в кресле] **за весь вечер не проронил ни слова.**

**Нет** в этом предложении (без приложения в квадратных скобках) **никаких запятых**, поэтому — как и положено по правилам обособления — ставим два тире и запятую, закрывающую причастный оборот.

2. Я, конечно же, оценила и Ваш вопрос, и Ваш ответ — и ничего менять не собираюсь.
   Для меня просто очень странно, что Вы сами не заметили "неправильность" у Розенталя, которую цитируете и при помощи которой строите свои рассуждения.

Пункт четвертый ([в примечании](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=111,4)).
[Одно тире (первое или второе) опускается] для внесения ясности, если приложение относится к одному из однородных членов предложения:
*В оранжерее разводились магнолии, к а м е л и и — **цветы Японии,** орхидеи и цикламены.*

При **такой пунктуации** приложение "цветы Японии" относится не только к камелиям, **но и к магнолиям** тоже (а это так и есть!).
[Камелию японскую](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%8F%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F) знают все. [**Магнолия**](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%8F) растет в Северной Америке и Восточной Азии (Китай, Корея, **Япония**), [орхидея](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D1%80%D1%85%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5) — по всему свету (кроме Антарктиды), [цикламен](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A6%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD) — в Средиземноморье.

Так что, думаю, правильно было бы написать **так** в формулировке:
для внесения ясности, если приложение относится к **одному** из однородных членов предложения или к их определенной **группе**.

Или исправить выделение шрифтом собственно в предложении:
*В оранжерее разводились м а г н о л и и, к а м е л и и — **цветы Японии,** орхидеи и цикламены.*

Comment: Добрый день, Римма, спасибо за ответ. К сожалению, не могу с Вами согласиться. У Розенталя четко прописано, что  приложение относится к одному однородному члену. Там же приведен  пример:За столом сидели хозяйка дома, её сестра — подруга моей жены, двое незнакомых мне лиц, моя жена и я;   Не могу сказать, откуда взялось предложение, но могу предположить, что именно камелии названы цветами Японии, так как они имели особое значение в японской культуре: разведение камелий становится одним из занятий сословия самураев. https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%8F

Comment: О правилах Розенталя. У меня нет претензий ни к правилам, ни к примерам, но есть претензии к редакции этих правил.   В двухтомнике правил 2005 года (у меня есть эта книга) редакция та же, Годы жизни Розенталя - 1900 -1994. Трудно сказать,что он редактировал лично. В Примечании  много неточностей:  1) одно тире и два тире, хотя там должно быть одно тире.2) в одну группу собраны разные примеры (по семантике, грамматике и интонации), что значительно затрудняет их понимание. Я сомневаюсь, что такое изложение материала одобрил бы сам Розенталь.