# Корректно ли употреблено тире в данном предложении? Если да, то по какому правилу?

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, тире

По сообщению пресс-службы организаторов акции — «Всеукраинского аграрного совета» (ВАС), они пригнали на площадь Конституции тракторы.

Самостоятельный поиск по справочникам не дал результата, т.к. смущает употребление одиночного тире, а не парного, если рассматривать выделенную часть как уточняющий член предложения.

Comment: Дополнительная информация: Галочку и лайк (верхний серый треугольник) можно комбинировать. На этом сайте, можно сказать, уже сложилась такая традиция.

Comment: @oleedd, Благодарю за совет.

Comment: Определитесь с числом: отчего совет (он же ВАС) не организатор, а организаторы, которые пригнали? Может быть — организаторов акции из «Всеукраинского аграрного совета»?

Comment: @shampar, предложение не мое, а было встречено мной в газетной статье, поэтому на Ваш вопрос ответить не могу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Корректно.

**Одно тире опускается, если по условиям контекста после обособленного приложения ставится запятая**:
*Если бы он привлёк к решению вопроса свой прибор — весы, то понял бы источник ошибки.   Используя специальное устройство для дыхания человека под водой — акваланг, можно погружаться на глубину в десятки метров.

Среди актёров передвижной труппы Сергея Эйзенштейна были юноши, впоследствии ставшие известными кинорежиссёрами, — Григорий Александров, Иван Пырьев, а также актёр Максим Штраух.*
Розенталь: http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=111 (см. примечания)

При этом элементы вокруг тире связаны определением понятия:
*Организаторы акции — это «Всеукраинский аграрный совет»*.

Похожий вопрос на эту тему: [Почему тиражируется ошибка в популярном учебнике русского языка?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/456866/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B0)